# Is it possible to embed "for loop" inside an "if statement" to compare multiple condition before continuing using c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop

In this program, the user must type in an 3 letter departing airport code (userFlight) and I will give them back the possible destinations.  To check that what they typed in is one of the valid airport codes (departureAirport) I want to compare userFlight and make sure it is one of the possible departureAirports which I have stored in a vector called flights[].  This code obviously isn't working, but is there a similar way to accomplish this?

```
 if             
        (for (j = 0, j < flights.size, j++)
        {
        (userFlight != flights[j].departAirport)
        })

    {return errorCode};

else
    {//doSomething()};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code structure you were aiming for is:

```
for (j = 0; j < flights.size(); j++)
    if (userFlight == flights[j].departAirport)
        break;

if ( j == flights.size() )   // we got to the end
    return errorCode;

doSomething(j);
```

However, this is a C-like code style. Not that there is anything wrong with that, but C++ allows for algorithms to be expressed more abstractly (and therefore, easier to read and maintain).  IMHO it would be better to use one of the other suggestions such as `std::set` or `std::find_if`.

Answer (score 6):

If it has a `operator<` inside which does compare like your condition, how about

```
if(std::find(flights.begin(), flights.end(), userFlight) != flights.end())
{
    /* found */
}
else
{
    /* not found */
}
```

Else, if you don't like that, just check if the loop runs through all indices:

```
size_t i;
for (i = 0, i < flights.size, i++)
{
    if(userFlight == flights[i].departAirport)
        break;
}
if(i < flights.size)
{
    /* found */
}
else
{
    /* not found */
}
```

But no, a syntax like you want doesn't exist.

Comment: Isn't it the other way aroud? If `i < flights.size` it was found

Comment: Separately, `find` needs `operator==` not `operator<`, and you need a predicate to check `.departAirport` unless you hack up the `Flight` class to have a `bool operator==(const Airport&) const`, which is an ugly idea IMHO - too easy to invoke accidentally in meaningless situations.  With a predicate, you can simplify to my answer - `std::any_of`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you actually want to have a [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) of departing airports.

```
std::set<std::string> departing_airports = {"DTW", "MKE", "MSP", };
assert(departing_airports.count("DTW") == 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).  Assuming `flights` contains objects of type `Flight`:

```
if (std::any_of(std::begin(flights), std::end(flights),
        [&](const Flight& f) { return userFlight == f.departAirport; }))
    return errorCode;

doSomething();
```